# Dropwizard app on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, dropwizard

I'd like to run a Dropwizard on the amazon cloud. Examples I've seen all seem to start with a docker image of the dropwizard app and deploy that. I was wondering if there was a simpler way of achieving the same.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can simply deploy the application jar file and run `java -jar` command on the EC2 box. Of course you'll probably want to automate this process, I recommend using the [boto](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) library for python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Boxfuse](https://boxfuse.com) to deploy your Dropwizard app to AWS. Boxfuse is able to read your Dropwizard yml configuration file and automatically provisioning and configure all required AWS infrastructure including ELBs, security groups, auto-scaling groups and the actual instances. All of that with just one command:

`boxfuse run my-dropwizard-app-1.0.jar -env=prod`

Here is a tutorial you can follow to get you started in no time: https://boxfuse.com/blog/dropwizard-aws

*Disclaimer: I am the founder and CEO of Boxfuse*

Comment: Instead of giving a priced solution and marketing your service, it would be nice to see a proper solution that encourages learning the "how to" rather than using a service.

Comment: The solution as presented costs absolutely nothing and greatly simplifies the entire process compared to doing everything manually yourself. Feel free to step up and contribute an alternative answer if you feel other ways to achieve this would be better.

Comment: The question targeted EC2 on Amazon. A commercial tool for a commercial PaaS provider is appropriate here. I agree that Axel should have pointed out that he is the author of boxfuse.